# Amcharts4 marker html-tooltips without hover event

Tags: angular, typescript, amcharts, amcharts4

I am using [this](https://codepen.io/team/amcharts/pen/Odrqrb) example to put map markers on click and my goal is displaying `mapMarker.tooltipHTML` elements by default, without hovering on them. Any alternatives such as creating html markers with are welcomed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well there are a couple of steps involved to getting `Tooltip`s to work the way you want out of the box. Firstly, tooltips are usually something of a singleton, instead of one per polygon or per `mapImage`, they actually share the one on their series. So each has to use their own tooltip (for the most part, `mapImage` below is the `imageSeries.mapImages.template`):

```js
mapImage.tooltip = new am4core.Tooltip();
```

Next, the condition that enables the tooltip, normally on hover, is if there's `tooltipText` or `tooltipHTML` set that isn't an empty string.

```js
mapImage.tooltipText = "Latitude: {latitude}\nLongitude: {longitude}";
```

Tooltips showing up on hover is the default behavior, the easiest way to prevent that is to disable mouse interactions on the `mapImage`:

```js
mapImage.interactionsEnabled = false;
```

Now, once a marker is created, we'll just show the tooltip:

```js
mapImage.events.once("inited", function(event) {
  event.target.showTooltip();
});
```

By default the tooltip `position` is already set to `"fixed"` and its `pointerOrientation` to `"vertical"`, we just need it to show up above the marker, which in this example is 32x32 px, scaled down 30%, so we just shift it up by 32 * .7 via the `mapImage`'s `tooltipY` property:

```js
mapImage.nonScaling = true; // this is also necessary so the size/vertical shift is predictably the same
mapImage.tooltipY = -32 * .7;
```

Last but not least, the tooltips don't maintain their position on zoom, so we'll have to do that ourselves by listening for zoom changes, converting map images' lat/long coords to chart x/y coords, and passing that to each tooltip:

```js
chart.events.on("zoomlevelchanged", function() {
  imageSeries.mapImages.each(function(mapImage) {
    var point = chart.geoPointToSVG({ latitude: mapImage.latitude, longitude: mapImage.longitude });
    mapImage.tooltip.moveTo({ x: point.x, y: point.y - (32 * .7)});
  });
});
```

Here's a demo:

https://codepen.io/team/amcharts/pen/698eb4a11c35733850fbc084631bfc21

#### Addendum (2019-04-11):

You can also [bind the latitude/longitude properties to data](https://www.amcharts.com/docs/v4/chart-types/map/#Binding_marker_properties_to_data) and create `mapImages` that way via the `addData` method, e.g.

```js
var mapImage = imageSeries.mapImages.template;
mapImage.propertyFields.latitude = "latitude";
mapImage.propertyFields.longitude = "longitude";

// You can even start off with some markers at the onset
// From our Animations along lines demo: https://www.amcharts.com/demos/animations-along-lines/
imageSeries.data = [
  { "latitude": 48.8567, "longitude": 2.3510, "name": "Paris"},
  { "latitude": 43.8163, "longitude": -79.4287, "name": "Toronto"},
  { "latitude": 34.3, "longitude": -118.15, "name": "Los Angeles"},
  { "latitude": 23, "longitude": -82, "name": "Havana"},
];

chart.seriesContainer.events.on("hit", function(ev) {
  var coords = chart.svgPointToGeo(ev.svgPoint);
  // var marker = imageSeries.mapImages.create();  
  // marker.latitude = coords.latitude;
  // marker.longitude = coords.longitude;
  imageSeries.addData({
    latitude: coords.latitude,
    longitude: coords.longitude,
  });
});
```

If you want to remove markers from the beginning of the `data` array, use the [`removeData` method](https://www.amcharts.com/docs/v4/reference/mapimageseries/#removeData_method). If you want to modify the `data` array using `Array.splice`, if the array is not empty afterwards, you'll have to run `imageSeries.invalidateData()` to update the view. If the array will be empty, it's better to just set `imageSeries.data = undefined` instead. Also keep in mind the [`addData` method](https://www.amcharts.com/docs/v4/reference/mapimageseries/#addData_method) has a 2nd parameter that also removes items from the beginning of the array.

Another note, you'll have to manually `dispose` the marker tooltips in their `"beforedisposed"` event.

Here's an updated and improved demo that includes some bug fixes:

https://codepen.io/team/amcharts/pen/fee1cb6db8971ec3eff6541ad52bab6d

Comment: Appreciate your detailed response

Comment: You're welcome! Feel free to ask away if you've any questions.

Comment: Also how can i bind markers data (id, title, latitude, longitude, etc.) to some object inside typescript? That would help me to delete markers without reloading map.

Comment: Could you clarify or give an example of how what kind of data would help you manage the markers? All the markers would be available via `imageSeries.mapImages` (`.each(...)` to iterate, `.getIndex(n)` to grab one), and their data (via `imageSeries.data = [...]`) is within `dataItem.dataContext` or as direct properties depending on what we're talking about.

Comment: Lets say we have array of objects
coords = [{
  longitude: number,
  latitude: number,
  title: string
}];
So goal is to bind this array to map markers so markers will be created from existing data, removed on splice() and pinned on push()

Comment: @BeckRakhimov I've updated the answer with a demo that is `data`-based. Instead of binding marker data, if you use the series' data array, you can modify that directly (and use `invalidateData()` or `invalidateRawData()` methods accordingly) or use `addData`/`removeData` methods and the markers will be updated (removed/added) accordingly. Haven't tested thoroughly so your mileage may vary, but I think the new demo is working well enough for a proof of concept.